# PHP/JS выполнение функции/проверки в самой переменной

Tags: php, javascript, синтаксис

Здравствуйте, подскажите как называется следующий синтаксис, когда непосредственно переменная играет роль функции:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode(' ', trim($str)), function($v) {
        return mb_strlen($v) > 1;
    });
```

И ответьте пожалуйста на второй вопрос,  есть ли полная проверка if else, которую так же можно произвести через переменную, подобно тернарной, то есть:

```
$a = if($b = 0) {
//присваиваем $a = 0
 return 0;
} else {
//присваиваем $a = 1
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: Кажется, метка `javascript` тут лишняя)

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko дело в том что я имею в виду и javascript тоже, просто example кода из php

Comment: Ну так это разные языки, и то что можно сделать в php, нельзя сделать в js и наоборот. Поэтому, пожалуйста, уточните ваш вопрос.

Comment: в первом случае у вас переменной присваивается значения функции `array_filer`. а вот третьим параметром фильтрации является анонимная функция.

Answer (score 4):

> когда непосредственно переменная играет роль функции

геттеры/сеттеры
getters/setters

#### php

```
 class Animal {
  function __get($property) {
    //...
  }

  function __set($property, $value) {
    //...
  }
}

$cow = new Animal;
$cow->weight = '1 ton'; // same as $cow->__set('weight', '1 ton')
print $cow->weight;     // same as print $cow->__get('weight');
```

- [php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php)
- [Getter’ы и Setter’ы — магия, которая должна знать свое место](https://phptime.ru/php-features/gettery-i-settery-magiya-kotoraya-dolzhna-znat-svoe-mesto.html)

#### js

```
let obj = {
    conteiner: {},
    get name() { return this.conteiner.name },
    set name(_name) {
        let type = typeof _name
        if ('string' == type) {
            this.conteiner.name = _name
            console.log('_name строка');
        } else if ('number' == type) {
            this.conteiner.name = ''+_name
            console.log('_name чисто');
        } else {
            this.conteiner.name = null
            console.log('невалидный _name');
        }
    },
}
obj.name = []
console.log(obj.name);
obj.name = 7
console.log(obj.name);
obj.name = 'qwa'
console.log(obj.name);
```

- [learn.javascript.ru](https://learn.javascript.ru/descriptors-getters-setters)

---

### тернарный оператор

#### php

```
// Пример использования тернарного оператора
$action = (empty($_POST['action'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['action'];

// Приведенный выше код аналогичен следующему блоку с использованием if/else
if (empty($_POST['action'])) {
    $action = 'default';
} else {
    $action = $_POST['action'];
}
```

#### js

```
let $action;
// Пример использования тернарного оператора
$action = (true) ? true : false

// Приведенный выше код аналогичен следующему блоку с использованием if/else
if (true) {
    $action = true
} else {
    $action = false
}
```

---

**UPD:**

### аналог php `__get` в JavaScript

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy
https://learn.javascript.ru/proxy

```js
let user = {};

let proxy = new Proxy(user, {
  get(target, prop) {
    console.log(`Чтение ${prop}`);
    return target[prop];
  },
  set(target, prop, value) {
    console.log(`Запись ${prop} ${value}`);
    target[prop] = value;
    return true;
  }
});

proxy.firstName = "Ilya"; // запись

proxy.firstName; // чтение

console.log(user.firstName); // Ilya
```

Answer (score 0):

**php**:

В первом примере переменная **`$arr`** принимает результат ф-ции [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php). Функцию в данном случае она не представляет. **`$arr`** будет присвоен отфильтрованный массив. Называйте это **присваиванием**:

```
$arr = array_filter(explode(' ', trim($str)), function($v) {
    return mb_strlen($v) > 1;
});
```

А это вообще не имеет никакого смысла:

```
$a = if($b = 0) {
//присваиваем $a = 0
    return 0;
} else {
//присваиваем $a = 1
    return 1;
}
```

Присваивание через тернарный оператор выглядит так:

```
$a = ($b == 0) ? 0 : 1; // сравнение $b и присваивание $a
// $a = 0

$a = ($b = 0) ? 0 : 1; // присваивание $b,сравнение и присваивание $a
// $a = 1
```

Если говорить про "**`синтаксис, когда непосредственно переменная играет роль функции`**", это называется [переменная функции](https://php.ru/manual/functions.variable-functions.html):

```
function foo(int $param) {
    return $param + 1;
}

$foo = 'foo'; // теперь переменная $foo вызовет функцию foo()

echo $foo(1); // 2
```

Так же в языке присутствуют [анонимные функции](https://coder-booster.ru/learning/php-beginners/closures-anonymous-function):

```
$a = function(int $param) {
    return $param + 1;
};

var_dump($a(1)); // int(2)
```